# Trying to replace the stars from the typical rate system and it is not working

Tags: html, css

The typical rate system uses stars but I want to use suns. I have the image of the stars and I made an image of identical size using suns instead of stars but when I upload that image and replace the image location in the code all the suns are grey even when there is a rating on it. In other words, a 3.0 should show 3 suns with color and 2 that are grey.

http://www.clearwaterfloridabeachrentals2.imbookingsecure.com/rentals/allrentals/weeklybeachrentalswithapool-clearwater-boatrentals-710/

I used:

```
span.stars, span.stars span {
    display: block;
    background: url('http://clearwaterfloridabeachrentals2.imbookingsecure.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/791/2015/09/suns.png') 0 -15px repeat-x;
    height: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Please include all relevant HTML and CSS in the question as well.

Comment: The question was answered perfectly below. Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you were using the same section of the image for both `span.stars` and `span.stars span`. Just adjust the background-image of `span.stars span` to reflect the selected star and you're good to go.

HTML:

```
<span class="stars">
    <span style="width: 64px;"></span>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
span.stars {
    display: block;
    background: url('http://www.clearwaterfloridabeachrentals2.imbookingsecure.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/791/2015/09/suns.png') 0 -15px repeat-x;
    height: 15px;
    width: 80px;
}
span.stars span {
    display: block;
    background: url('http://www.clearwaterfloridabeachrentals2.imbookingsecure.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/791/2015/09/suns.png') 0 -1px repeat-x;
    height: 15px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfyjL59L/)

Comment: This makes better sense to me. I used the css and it worked perfectly.